# How accurate are astronomical observations around black holes? Can they distinguish between the following two scenarios?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astronomy, event-horizon, singularities

1. Scenario 1
   As Schwarzschild imagined. All of the matter in the black hole is at the centre, forming a singularity. The formula for the event horizon that bears his name is

$$R  =  \frac{2GM}{c^2}$$

2. Scenario 2
   Instead, all of the matter that has entered or formed the black hole, remains at the event horizon. This matter has potential energy, lots of it. In fact the mass of the potential energy is equal to the mass of the matter. The formula for the event horizon is now
   $$R  =  \frac{GM}{c^2}$$

The event horizon now has one half of the radius as before. This formula, which describes an orbit, is now the same as Newton's. Just a coincidence I think, Newton could never have imagined his formula being used like this.

How could Scenario 2 occur? If a black hole were a 4-dimensional ball of spacetime, it would have a 3-dimensional surface, a 3-sphere. This 3-sphere would have more than enough volume to contain the matter in the black hole. The Schwarzschild event horizon would be a 3-sphere. There would now be no physical singularity.

Comment: All we can say about your idea is that it's not consistent with GR. Within GR, there's no reason for matter to stop at the event horizon. To determine what the experimental consequences of your idea are, you need to provide a complete mathematical theory that allows one to calculate what would happen in such a scenario. The first two tests I'd want to see a calculation for are the waveform for two inspiraling binary black holes (as observed by LIGO and Virgo) and images produced by the event horizon telescope.

Comment: GR may not predict it, but I think it allows scenario 2. In lieu of my lack of ability to follow the suggested route I wondered whether the matter could be settled by direct observation.

Comment: In order to compare with experiment, you need to make a prediction. What specific predictions is your proposal making? If the claim is that the event horizon should be half as big for a given mass "somehow" (without a theory that backs up how this would happen), that seems inconsistent with measurements of the mass and event horizon of M87* from the Event Horizon Telescope (as well as independent measurements of the mass). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messier_87#Supermassive_black_hole_M87*

Answer (score 1):

Astronomical measurements of supermassive black holes have been able to estimate the mass of the central object by examining the dynamics of orbiting objects. This has been done for both the Sgr A* black hole at the centre of the Milky Way and the black hole at the centre of M87.

Subsequent to that, more detailed measurements, for example by interferometric imaging with the VLTI and the Event Horizon Telescope respectively have been able to uncover evidence of (General) Relativistic effects that depend on the ratio $r/r_s$, where $r_s = 2GM/c^2$ is the Schwarzschild radius. These include the orbital precession and relativistic redshift of stars that pass very close to Sgr A* and the radius of the "black hole shadow" in the case of the M87 black hole.

In both these cases, the value of $r/r_s$ implied by the astronomical measurements of relativistic effects gives an $r_s$ that agrees with $2GM/c^2$ inferred from the earlier dynamical measurements.

Your scenario 2 has no merit. Matter cannot accumulate at $r = r_s/2$, because matter cannot be stationary at $r < r_s$ and must move inward (to smaller $r$).

The presence of a singularity cannot be inferred from these astronomical observations and by [Birkhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)), a spacetime that looks like it is governed by the Schwarzschild metric beyond some radial coordinate could result from any spherically symmetric mass distribution interior to that radial coordinate. Indeed, to an external observer, any mass that falls into the black hole will be effectively stationary at the event horizon ("effectively", since $dr/dt$ becomes very small but never actually reaches zero from the point of view of an external observer) but if that mass is distributed in a spherically symmetric way, the metric outside is indistinguishable from that due to a Schwarzschild black hole.

Comment: But does the standard view allow for the fact that matter at the event horizon will have potential energy. Apart from anything else, how will that matter shed this potential energy as it falls inwards?

Comment: @safesphere Moving towards smaller $r$ can, and usuallly is, labelled "inward". And it IS "effectively stationary", since at no point does $dr/dt$ ever become zero.